# How can I specify an agent for post action in Jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run the post part of my declarative pipeline inside a docker container. And I don't know how to set the agent only for post.

Sample of my pipeline

```
post {
        always {
            echo 'This will always run'
        }
        success {
            mail ## my mail content;
        }
}
```

And I want to run this mail command in a docker container.

Comment: have you tried 
stage('Example Test') {
            agent { docker 'openjdk:8-jre' } 
            steps {
                echo 'Hello, JDK'
                sh 'java -version'
            }
        }
    }

Comment: I want to use the agent for post block of pipeline not for post-stage.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `node(...){...}` block within the post steps, with or without the `script {...}` block as applicable:

```
post {
    always {
        echo 'This will always run'
    }
    success {
        node('docker') {
            script {
                mail ## my mail content;
            }
        }
    }
}
```